# Load level after playing Intro video unity3d c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have start a new game in unity3d and i have done a video intro to start at the begin and after the video is finish i want to load the menu scene i try to atach the script to load the menu scene in a sfere object but wen i start its go on menu scene before to show the video.
the video its play by the movie player 
how can i detect wen the video its finish?
how can i perform this on c# code?

On this scene wen its start its play the intro video 
and i need to detect wen the video its finish to make it load the menu scene

[image: Image from scene]

Answer (score 0):

Well after to check a bit the script that control the play, stop, loop, etc i have try to insert my code after the code were say: if its not loop then stop the video and i have insert the application.load after it and its work perfect.

Comment: Please translate this into coherent English.